# misplaced legend on a scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am using matplotlib 1.10.1.
The following code plots a scatter plot and adds a legend in the "best" location.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(1.1,2.8)
for i in range(0, 5):
    plt.scatter(x, x, label='Scatter%d' % i)
#plt.plot(x, x)
#plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

However, the legend appears in the upper right corner covering some points. I was expecting it to appear in the upper left corner where there is no data. Plotting a line instead of a scatter plot seems to produce the expected behaviour.

Is there a way to fix the "best" legend location for scatter plots?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have encountered [this issue](https://github.com/wmak/matplotlib/commit/f6a28ba65af63ee7f6f3ef14786d31e01993415d) and the patch suggested in the thread there has not made it into the master branch.

So I think your only option is to apply it manually.